# Python 3.5: Split Sentence Before and After Speech Marks

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on some code which normalises a set of sentences to be grammatically correct which means that if there is a space between punctuation and the word before it, this will get removed etc. If this was the entered string:

```
Hello ! My name is Bob and it is nice to meet you !
```

It would be condensed to this:

```
Hello! My name is Bob and it is nice to meet you!
```

The problem comes with speech marks where they are not just stuck to the end of the word to it's left. For example,

```
Bob said " This is fun ! "
```

isn't condensed to:

```
Bob said" This is fun!"
```

Simply put, when speech is used, the first speech mark sticks to the right of the word and the second one sticks to the left of the word.

After thinking about this, I put together the following code:

```
import re

sentence = input("Enter a string")
sentence = (re.sub(r'\s+([?.,!:;])', r'\1', sentence))
space_sentence = re.findall('"[^"]*|[^"]+', sentence)

for i in (0, (len(space_sentence)-1)):
    if space_sentence[i-1] and space_sentence[i+1] == '"':
        re.sub(r'\s+', '',space_sentence[i])


output = (''.join(space_sentence))
print(output)
```

The basic idea of this is that it will go through the string and split it before and after a speech mark is found.

Eg

```
Bob said " I like fish " before walking away .
```

would become

```
['Bob said ', '"', ' I like fish ', '"', ' before walking away.']
```

and what I could then do is check for whether anything in the list has a speech mark either side before removing the space at the beginning and end of this before putting it all back together and therefore removing only the spaces between the speech marks and the speech.

```
Bob said "I like fish" before walking away.
```

The problem is that I'm finding it difficult to cut before and after the speech marks (the code I've given will only cut before) and so I therefore wanted to ask if there was a simple way of doing this? Also feel free to correct any mistakes I've made elsewhere.

Sorry if my code is pretty messy at the moment, I'm no coding expert haha :)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A non-greedy match between the pairs would work:

```
import re
s = 'He said , " This is fun ! " She said , " No it is not . "'
s = re.sub(r'\s+([?.,!:;])', r'\1', s)
print(s)
s = re.sub(r'"\s+(.*?)\s+"', r'"\1"', s)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
He said, " This is fun! " She said, " No it is not. "
He said, "This is fun!" She said, "No it is not."
```